# Image not showing in imageview when selecting rear camera pictures

Tags: android, image, camera, imageview, android-studio

I have a weird issue running in my application. My application works like this, something similar to setting up your profile picture on Facebook or Twitter.

Similar to that I have an `ImageView` which when I click, invokes an intent to open my gallery pictures. But the issue is, all my pictures get selected expect for those that I clicked with my rear camera. The resolution of my camera pictures are 4208x3120.

I tried to re-size the pictures using `Bitmap.createscaledimage()` method as my first option but no luck (rear camera images get selected but are not showing in the imageview and here's my option 2 code.

```
public class bitmaptest extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    // load the origial BitMap (500 x 500 px)
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
           R.drawable.android);

    int width = bitmapOrg.width();
    int height = bitmapOrg.height();
    int newWidth = 200;
    int newHeight = 200;

    // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // createa matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // rotate the Bitmap
    matrix.postRotate(45);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, 
                      width, height, matrix, true); 

    // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap 
    // to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

    // set the Drawable on the ImageView
    imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);

    // center the Image
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);

    // add ImageView to the Layout
  }
}
```

Even this turns out to be negative. Only pictures that are taken from the front camera appear on my imageview.

When I select any rear camera images , it again gets selected but doesn't show up on the `ImageView`. 
Can someone help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find solution for this?

Comment: Subasa : hi,Yeah its solved. You have to convert the image to bitmap image and use sample size to convert and resize the image without the pixel loss and try to put them in the image view. For your reference I am linking the google developer (android guide) , I understood from this page and worked it out and got my results finally.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Let me know your luck on this once you get your solution.